# Json.Net can't deserialize from dynamic object to nullable<short>

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, nullable

I have the following JSON being sent to an MVC controller:

```
{
  "CId": 374,
  "CultureId": 1,
  "VGS": null,
  "DisplayOrder": 1
}
```

I am using JSON.Net to convert this to a dynamic object and later assigning the properties into an entity:

```
public partial class FooEntity
{
    public short DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> VGS { get; set; }
    public short CId { get; set; }
    public short CultureId { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the VGS property we are assigning into is a nullable short, however when trying to create a new instance of the entity and assign the values, I get an error when trying to assign the VGS:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payload);
var foo = new FooEntity();
foo.CId = data.CId;
foo.CultureId = data.CultureId;
foo.VGS = data.VGS; // Errors here
foo.DisplayOrder = data.DisplayOrder;
```

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

As far as I can tell, the json is correct to deserialize into a null value, and since I am assigning into a nullable value, I'm not sure what is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe `VGS` is being deserialized as `object`, and that's why you can't assign it to a `Nullable<sort>`

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooEntity>(payload);Can you try with generic?

Comment: Also, you should prefer `short?` over `Nullable<short>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.Net does not know what to parse `VGS` to, which will make it an `object`. Then you cannot assign an `object` to `VGS`. Below is a working example. It can be solved in several ways:

**Solution 1**: Use explicit cast.

```
var payload = "{\"CId\": 374, \"CultureId\": 1,\"VGS\": null,\"DisplayOrder\": 1}";
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooEntity>(payload);
var foo2 = new FooEntity();
foo.CId = dyn.CId;
foo.CultureId = dyn.CultureId;
foo.VGS = (short?)dyn.VGS; // Note the explicit cast.
foo.DisplayOrder = dyn.DisplayOrder;
```

**Solution 2**: Specify type.

```
var payload = "{\"CId\": 374, \"CultureId\": 1,\"VGS\": null,\"DisplayOrder\": 1}";
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooEntity>(payload); // Specify type.
var foo = new FooEntity();
foo.CId = data.CId;
foo.CultureId = data.CultureId;
foo.VGS = data.VGS;
foo.DisplayOrder = data.DisplayOrder;
```

But then there's really no reason to use `dynamic` at all. You can serialize it directly to the entity you want.

```
FooEntity entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooEntity>(payload);
```

Comment: Solution 2 wasnt possible because the actual payload is more complicated but solution 1 worked. Thank you.

Comment: The first solution does not really solve the issue, even if you don't specify a cast, it works fine. Netwtonsft.Json has implicit conversion operators to and from most built-in types, and this is not an issue. The issue here is something else, but hopefully the second one worked for the OP.

Comment: You can see here that `JToken` has almost all implicit conversions to built-in types. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/b8e60c773bfbd765b9131694a01569e067b37d99/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs